# Why is OneDrive syncing files across with hidden attribute set?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, onedrive

I have a windows 7 PC with onedrive app installed.  I have copied files to that folder.

Now they all show up using the OneDrive GUI on Windows 8.1, but if I browse using the command shell ( even with elevated priv ), the files are only visible using

```
dir /ah
```

which seems a bit odd since my applications also can't see these files.

What's the point?  Or is there some other meaning to this?

I've tried resyncing on the Windows 8.1 PC but no cigar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your files are available online only, see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/onedrive-online-available-offline.

Files that are online available only will have the attribute hidden.